# SQL Query: number per quarter hour

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have a sql table with 4 columns (id (char), ref(varchar), received(timestamp), sent(timestamp)).
I would like to make a sql query to get the number of references per quarter of an hour according to the 'received' column.
I've been searching some time but haven't find a real solution to do it in a query.
Is there someone who has any idea how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,

Tom

Comment: What have you tried so far? Oracle has built-in functionality for converting timestamps to different "time" outputs.

Comment: I find several queries to get them by hour, but they need to be per quarter hour.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [TRUNC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions220.htm#i79761) and [EXTRACT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions059.htm#i1017161) to group your data per quarter-hour:

```
SELECT date_hour, time_quarter_hour, COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT TRUNC(your_timestamp, 'hh24') date_hour,
               floor(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM your_timestamp) / 15) time_quarter_hour
          FROM your_table)
 GROUP BY date_hour, time_quarter_hour
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for!
I wouldn't have found it on my own.

Answer (score 1):

See below a try. Timestamp is not important here, can be a Date.

```
select 
   trunc(sysdate, 'hh24') + trunc(to_char(sysdate,'mi')/15)*15/1440 
from dual;
```